# Can we retrieve the role of the users in Marketing CLoud Account, using SOAP API?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketingcloudapi

Is there any way to retrieve the role of the users in Marketing CLoud Account, using SOAP API?
I am able to retrieve other details like email, BU, UserID, ActiveFlag using the SOAP API call, but there is no object property to retrieve the user role assigned.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried the Role object : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/role.htm

Comment: Hi @SwatiMishra, thanks a lot, I am able to retrieve the user role details using the AccountUser object calling the Roles property of it.